# How to export/import variables between different files - ESM not CJS (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

I need to create a JS RPG CLI game.
I have a JS file with a function that generates random number for *player health*. That part I need to put in a variable so that it fixes one randomly generated number that I can use later for battling in another JS file. When I do that, how to export that variable so that I can include and use it in another files. So basically I need to share it between three files: `randomHealth.js` where it's generated, `stats.js` where it gets displayed and after the battle updated and `fight.js` where it's used for fighting.

```js
// randomHealth.js
let randomHealth = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 + 1)
}

export default randomHealth


// stats.js
import randomHealth from "./random/randomHealth.js"

let stats = () => {
  console.log("STATS")
  console.log(randomHealth())
}

export default stats



// fight.js
import clear from "console-clear"
import randomHealth from "../utils/random/randomHealth.js"

const fight = () => {
  clear(true)

  let playerHealth = randomHealth()
  async function battle() {}

  battle()
}

export default fight
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// stats.js
import randomHealth from "./random/randomHealth.js"

export let playerHealthDisplay = randomHealth()

let stats = () => {
  console.log("STATS")
  console.log("Health - " + playerHealthDisplay)
}

export default stats


// fight.js
let playerHealth = playerHealthDisplay
```

You need one `playerHealth` for the display and another for reusing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// stats.js
import randomHealth from "./random/randomHealth.js"

export let playerHealthDisplay = randomHealth()

let stats = () => {
  console.log("STATS")
  console.log("Health - " + playerHealthDisplay)
}

export default stats


// fight.js
let playerHealth = playerHealthDisplay
```